# Реализовать поиск в Nagivation Drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, search, android-navigation-drawer

Для приложения использую шаблон Navigation Drawer. Сверху в меню есть значок поиска. Что нужно сделать, чтобы после нажатия на этот значок открылась строка поиска, и как потом обработать событие изменения текста в этой строке? Либо реализовать поиск каким-то другим образом. К примеру, как это сделано в Play Market

Answer (score 0):

Реализация **поиска** в меню ничем не отличается от его реализации в любой другой части приложения.

Только вместо значка и отдельной строки поиска, лучше используйте **SearchView**, который представляет из себя *значок поиска* и *строку*, появляющуюся при нажатии на значок.

Для обработки и вывода результатов воспользуйтесь интерфейсом `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`. Так же, можно использовать `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...})`. Наверняка есть и другие способы.